# Construyendo app con API REST en Symfony3 y AngularJS, problemas con el enrutamiento

Tags: php, angularjs, api, symfony3, router

Buenas,

En esta ocasión me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación nueva y voy a construir la app con una API REST en `Symfony3` y el frontend que consuma la API en `AngularJS`, tengo varias dudas y espero me puedan ayudar, son las siguientes.

He creado dos carpetas:

```
backend/
frontend/
```

En la carpeta backend tengo todo lo referente a la API REST con Symfony3 y en la carpeta frontend, los archivos de AngularJS, mi pregunta es ¿si es servidor corre en la carpeta backend, como hago para que renderice las paginas que estan del lado del cliente en la carpeta frontend?

Por ejemplo, cuando coloque la ruta `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` este me renderice el archivo que esta en frontend/src/home.html

**Mi mayor duda es, como hacer que las rutas definidas en el servidor sean solo de la API y las demás o cualquier otro sea aislada de las de la API osea que se definan en el frontend o en una app movil**

Gracias espero alguien me ayude con la configuración y me explique o me de un enlace donde lo expliquen, gracias de ante mano a todos.

Saludos.

Comment: Manejas las rutas con anotaciones o yml? En este caso yo utilizaría yml que me da mayor libertad en la definición de las mismas

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu repuesta, pero es indiferente si uso YML o no, creo que no esparte del problema que tengo.

Comment: Lo usual es tratarlos como 2 aplicaciones distintas. Puedes correr cada una en `virtual hosts` distintos y configurar el servidor para que dependiendo del dominio, cargue los scripts de una carpeta u otra.